# How can I tell if my PHP S3 class putObjectFile() process has completed?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, amazon-s3

I am using PHP S3 class from undesigned to put uploaded audio files to my amazon S3 bucket using the following syntax -

```
$s3 = new S3("awsAccessKey", "awsSecretKey");
$s3->putObjectFile(params);
```

then my code continues and uses CURL to call another server to retrieve the file in the S3 bucket and transcode the audio.

How can I tell when the putObject has completed successfully? what I am noticing is that the transcode process may fail, and I assume it is because the file has not completed being put to S3. I had assumed that the next line of code will not be executed until the putObject line has completed, do I need to wrap this in an `if($s3->putObjectFile(...)) { }` ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could use trycatch()

```
try
{
   $s3 = new S3("awsAccessKey", "awsSecretKey");
   $s3->putObjectFile(params);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

in your function you would then throw an error with

```
throw new exception('error, could not complete, ....');
```

eg:

```
if(!dosomething) //if something failed
{
   throw new exception('error, could not complete, ....');
}
```

Using this it will stop executing code as soon as an exception is thrown. and then you just echo out or you could store it in a variable and then echo out wherever you want

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. I really want the code to wait until the $s3->putObjectFile() has completed then to continue on to the next line of code. So - 

if($s3->putObjectFile()) {
  //execute this code only when putObjectFile() is complete. 
}

but maybe this is not possible if the putObjectFile() is asynchronous?